# C Compile Error (No such file or directory, compilation terminated)

Tags: c, compilation, cmd, mingw, glut

I'm on Windows trying to learn some OpenGL. I Installed mingw and have a test file.
I put my test.c file in a glut folder, which contains glut files such as the glut32.dll and library file.
I used mingw in cmd to run the file using this:

```
gcc opengl.c -o opengl -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

And I got this error:

```
opengl.c:1:23 fatal error: GLUT/glut.h: No such file or directory
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

compilation terminated.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, anybody know? Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the `glut` development package? Is `GLUT/glut.h` in the compilers default include search path?

Comment: Try specifying path to the directory having the header file  using `-I` option.

Comment: Header names are case-sensitive if you're under *nix systems.

Comment: @Mauren I'm running Windows 8. Followed what it says on the site and no luck

Comment: @JoachimPileborg could you elaborate on how I do this? I'm running Windows 8 and I'm not sure what to do. I have downloaded GLUT 3.7, not sure what to do with it all though. And how do I add glut.h to default search path, thanks

Comment: @Mauren MinGW is a Windows compiler.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MadHatter I did that and the error went away but now it's saying it cant find the libraries

Comment: Try adding the path to directory having shared library files using `-L` option.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to check that there *is* a `glut.h` file, in a `GLUT` folder.

Then you tell the compiler where to find it using the `-I` command-line option (note, it's capital `i`, not `1` or `l`):

```
$ gcc -I/path/to/folder opengl.c -o opengl -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

In the command above, replace `/path/to/folder` to the folder where the `GLUT` folder is.

You might also need to tell the linker where the libraries are, which is done with the `-L` option:

```
$ gcc -I/path/to/folder opengl.c -o opengl -L/path/to/libs -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

Comment: I removed the GL/ and I used include "glut.h" instead of <> and it worked but gave me a load of errors about missing libraries. The .c file is inside the glut folder so I thought it would work. Do I have to specify the -I path and -L path every time I run it or can I set them up ? Also, I tried it just there. I did the -L but it says it can't find any of those extra elements like -lGl and all

Comment: @AndyOHartIf you don't copy the headers/libraries to anywhere the compiler looks at by default, you will have to add those flags.

Comment: @AndyOHart See e.g. [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-09/msg00216.html) for how to find out the default include search path.

Comment: @Okay thanks. It gave me this error on compile: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGL

Comment: @AndyOHart To find out the default search path for libraries, run the command `gcc -print-search-dirs | grep libraries`

Comment: How do I do that using Mingw? Grep didn't seem to be recognized?

Comment: @AndyOHart Skip the pipe and the `grep` part, it just means you will get some unrelated data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49658/discussion-between-andyohart-and-joachim-pileborg)

Comment: got this when I did it install: c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/
programs: =c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gc
c/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/mingw32/4.8.1/;
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/
libraries: =c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/m
ingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/ming
w/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/

Answer (score 0):

USER DEFINED HEADERS SYNTAX IS  #include "name of file.h " ....... there is no "<" or  ">"....because that just asks the  compiler to check in its directories were all headers are stored ...wereas " " ask compiler to check current directory....and of course make sure the header is defined in the same directory as ur main.c

Comment: I don't think that `<GLUT/glut.h>` was a user-defied header, and btw all common compilers (like gcc) check for the header file in the current directory if it could not be found elsewhere