# Unable to understand the errors given by running make

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

My directory structure is `/home/akshayaj/Desktop/System Programs/dictionary/`

Inside dictionary I have 3 files:

- libdictionary.c (implements all the functions except main),
- libentrypoint.c (contains main()),
- libdictionary.h (contains declaration of all the functions)

Both C files include the header file

Now I wrote a make file for the above project. It goes like this:-

```
CFLAGS=-I /home/akshayaj/Desktop/System Programs/dictionary/
libdict: libentrypoint.o libdictionary.o
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o libdict libentrypoint.o libdictionary.o
libentrypoint.o: libentrypoint.c libdictionary.h
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c libentrypoint.c
libdictionary.o: libdictionary.c libdictionary.h
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c libdictionary.c
```

Now when I ran it, I got these errors:-

```
cc -I /home/akshayaj/Desktop/System Programs/dictionary/ -c libentrypoint.c


cc: error: Programs/dictionary/: No such file or directory


make: *** [libentrypoint.o] Error 1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Note:- In CFLAGS  I have given the whole path because I saw it in a similar question, but that didn't work. Here is the link to that question.

[C Compile Error (No such file or directory, compilation terminated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377762/c-compile-error-no-such-file-or-directory-compilation-terminated)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use spaces (or other strange chars) in your paths for code. You'll save yourself quoting headaches for makefiles and other build infrastructure.

Comment: What Mat above means is: your path `/home/akshayaj/Desktop/System Programs/dictionary/` contains a space character that breaks the path for `cc`. `cc` interprets that as _two_ separate paths. You either have to escape that space, or wrap the path or, as suggested and intelligent: not use such spaces in folder names.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use path `/home/akshayaj/Desktop/System\ Programs/dictionary/`, where `\` handles the space.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how that command line would be parsed...

```
cc -I /home/akshayaj/Desktop/System Programs/dictionary/ -c libentrypoint.c
^^ ^------------------------------^ ^------------------^ ^-----------------^
 |               |                           |                     |
Command       -I arg                      BAD ARG               -c arg
```

As you can see, the space between "System" and "Programs" is read as a separator between two command args.

Your options are either:

1. Change the path so that the space is removed (recommended). e.g. `/home/akshayaj/Desktop/System-Programs/dictionary/`.
2. Add a backslash before the space to escape it. e.g.:

   ```
   /home/akshayaj/Desktop/System\ Programs/dictionary/
   ```

As a general rule, it's not wise to use paths with spaces in them when building stuff using make, or just building stuff in general. It makes ambiguities like this hard to solve.